# Add xml child to array php

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to add each `<outfit>Subnodes</outfit>` subnodes to an array using php.

**My actual code:**

```
public static function get_outfits($username) {
   $files = self::user_files($username);
   $data  = self::request($files['outfits']);
   $data  = @simplexml_load_string($data);
   if ( $data && count(@$data->xpath('//outfits/outfit')) > 0 ) {
      foreach(@$data->xpath('//outfits/outfit/*') as $items) {
         $response['outfits']['items'][] = array(
            "url"          => (string)$items['url'],
            "c"            => (string)$items['c'],
            "c2"           => (string)$items['c2'],
            "displayName"  => (string)$items['displayName'],
            "z"            => (string)$items['z'],
            "id"           => (string)$items['id'],
            "isUgc"        => (string)$items['isUgc']
         );
      }
   }
   return (isset($response) ? $response : false);
}
```

**The xml document looks like the following:** http://outfits.zwinky.com/users/220/287/_perverted/outfits.xml

Sadly the code is saving every existing child into one array. But I'm trying to create an array index for each `<outfit></outfit>` node which should contain the child elements.

**For example:**

Array[0] = Everything between the first `<outfit><outfit>`

Array[1] = Everything between the second `<outfit><outfit>`

Does anyone have an idea, how to create this?

Comment: You could start by removing all the `@` error silencing and check each statement for any errors. Displaying any you find will probably tell you what is wrong, without any help from us!

Comment: The silencing is related to other code inside the class. It works, but its not working as i want it to work. The code does return any child element. But sadly each child in an array. This is actually how i want it: Array[0] = Everything between the first <outfit><outfit>

Array[1] = Everything between the second <outfit><outfit>

Comment: _It works, but its not working as i want it to work_ **= It does not work**

Comment: please add a minimum valid XML example. The link may be dead one day, then your question will be useless to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two loops, one for the `outfit` elements and one for the inner `item` elements. On the other side, you don't need the condition, because iterating an empty array/node list works fine.

```
$outfits = new SimpleXmlElement($xml);

$result = [];
foreach ($outfits->xpath('outfit') as $outfit) {
  $items = [];
  foreach ($outfit->xpath('*') as $item) {
    $items[$item->getName()] = [
      "url" => (string)$item['url'],
      "c" => (string)$item['c'],
      "c2" => (string)$item['c2'],
      "displayName" => (string)$item['displayName'],
      "z" => (string)$item['z'],
      "id" => (string)$item['id'],
      "isUgc" => (string)$item['isUgc']
    ];
  }
  $result[] = [
    'name' => (string)$outfit['name'],
    'items' => $items
  ];
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "babe13"
    ["items"]=>
    array(14) {
      ["head"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["url"]=>
        string(51) "http://.../assets/babe/heads/01/head1"
        ["c"]=>
        string(8) "0xF4C4A4"
        ["c2"]=>
        string(8) "0xffffff"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["z"]=>
        string(5) "33000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["isUgc"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ["face"]=>
      array(7) {
        ["url"]=>
        string(50) "http://.../assets/babe/faces/01/grl1"
        ["c"]=>
        string(3) "0x0"
        ["c2"]=>
        string(8) "0xFF0000"
        ["displayName"]=>
        string(5) "girl1"
        ["z"]=>
        string(5) "34000"
        ["id"]=>
        string(8) "20014794"
        ["isUgc"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output you want :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/heads/01/head1
            [c] => 0xF4C4A4
            [c2] => 0xffffff
            [displayName] => 
            [z] => 33000
            [id] => 
            [isUgc] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/faces/01/grl1
            [c] => 0x0
            [c2] => 0xFF0000
            [displayName] => girl1
            [z] => 34000
            [id] => 20014794
            [isUgc] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://assets.zwinky.com/assets/babe/midsections/01/ms1
            [c] => 0xBCE4FE
            [c2] => 
            [displayName] => 
            [z] => 9000
            [id] => 
            [isUgc] => 
        )

... etc etc
```

Then all you need to do is change the code to this

```
public static function get_outfits($username) {
   $files = self::user_files($username);
   $data  = self::request($files['outfits']);
   $data  = @simplexml_load_string($data);
   if ( $data && count(@$data->xpath('//outfits/outfit')) > 0 ) {
      foreach(@$data->xpath('//outfits/outfit/*') as $items) {

         // $response['outfits']['items'][] = array(

         $response[] = array(
            "url"          => (string)$items['url'],
            "c"            => (string)$items['c'],
            "c2"           => (string)$items['c2'],
            "displayName"  => (string)$items['displayName'],
            "z"            => (string)$items['z'],
            "id"           => (string)$items['id'],
            "isUgc"        => (string)$items['isUgc']
         );
      }
   }
   return (isset($response) ? $response : false);
}
```

Comment: Yea but i need an array index per <outfit></outfit>

Comment: Means for each <outfit></outfit> i need an index inside the array containing the child elements